# Magento 1.9.3.2 - Edit Order - Uncheck "Email Order Confirmation" checkbox by default

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am quite new to Magento, and have a store with Magento 1.9.3.2.
I have a requirement to Uncheck "Email Order Confirmation" checkbox by default which appears when I try to Edit an order - as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

Can someone share if this is possible to do and what is the best way to achieve this.

I have seen `System->Configuration->Sales->Sales Email` and an option to disable the order emails - however, I doubt that this will disable the order emails in general instead of just unchecking it optionally only for Edit Order scenario.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: The answer suggests something else....indeed something to do in the programming....yeah but makes more sense to put this in magento's dedicated forum

Comment: An answer that is about programming doesn't mean the original question was about programming. "How do I get to the post office?" "Go up the hill and turn left at the first intersection." - this doesn't mean the question was about hill climbing or intersections.

Comment: I wish you know that Magento is also an open source program written in PHP....If you think whatever you are saying is correct then go ahead and "vote for close" for all other Magento questions as well on Stack Overflow - FYI: there are more than 40000+ question on Magento on this website...and you seems to prove all those thousands of people wrong who had asked those questions

Comment: Yes, if they aren't asking a programming question then they are wrong. Just because software is programmed it doesn't mean that every question about the software is a programming question.

Comment: Questions that are on topic here are about **"a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; AND is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"**.

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers - This is met"

......."AND is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development - Answer suggest this has met" ......

it doesn't mean that every question about the software is a programming question - In this question case, it is indeed a programming question and the answer suggests that

Comment: By The Way....how do you define a programming question?.....what is a program? and How you are sure that Magento is not a Program?

Comment: The question has to meet the criteria, not the answer. Your question doesn't contain any reference to programming so it can't be "unique to software development".

Comment: It has a reference to program (which is magento) and a problem in that program (which is related to programming) - specifically "how can I uncheck a checkbox by default" in this program called magento - How do you say it is not programming? As I asked before; what is your definition of programming?

Comment: I don't need to give a definition of programming - SO gives us one already: "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers." Just because your question is about Magento (which is a program) it doesn't mean it is about programming. Your question could have been answer by a config setting or the like - it's not a programming-related question.

Comment: Also, "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Comment: And, "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this file path :- **\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\create\totals.phtml**
and open that file and over there you can see below code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="send_confirmation" name="order[send_confirmation]" value="1" checked="checked"/>
```

and remove checked html attribute and you are done it. hope it helps :)